# How to convert rows into columns and query on them in Mysql?

Tags: mysql, pivot, eav

I have three tables **Patients**, which contains the name of my patients, **Controls** which represents the UI controls which could be drawn for each illness , and **ControlsValues** table which contains the values of the controls submitted for each Patient

Lets have some data
***Patients*** Table

```
|ID  | Name |
|-----------|
| 1  | Ara  |
| 2  | Sada |
```

***Controls*** table

```
|ID  | Text | Type     |
|-----------|----------|
| 1  | age  | textbox  |
| 2  |alergy| checkbox |
```

Then the ***controlsValues*** table which is where I want to query at

```
|ID  | contrlId | value    | patientId |
|---------------|----------|-----------|
| 1  | 1        | 23       | 1         |
| 2  | 2        | true     | 1         |
| 3  | 1        | 26       | 2         |
| 4  | 2        | false    | 2         |
```

here my problem occurs when I want to return that patient from `ControlsValues` table that has the (`controlId=1` AND `value=23`) and (`controlId=2` AND `value=true`) 
in this case the condition is on two rows not two columns which it is not possible , so I desided to change the rows into the columns depending on `controlId` but I dont know how and I have been searching for 2 days and seen a lot of samples but none of them helped me to solve my problem

Comment: What is the query you tried so far ?

Comment: @MySQLRockstar i have tried many none worked , do not know which one to put

Comment: Install this [Stored Procedure](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/pivot) and it will generate the `SELECT` you need.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this kind of "solution":

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d33a95/18

It is not an "pivot-table" solution, but maybe it solves your problem - if I have understood it correctly.

Here are the tables / data used:

```
CREATE TABLE `patients` (
`ID` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
`Name` VARCHAR( 50 ) NOT NULL ,
PRIMARY KEY ( `ID` )
);
CREATE TABLE `controls` (
`ID` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
`Text` VARCHAR( 50 ) NOT NULL ,
`Type` VARCHAR( 50 ) NOT NULL ,
PRIMARY KEY ( `ID` )
); 
CREATE TABLE `controlvalues` (
`ID` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
`ControlID` INT NOT NULL ,
`Value` VARCHAR( 50 ) NOT NULL ,
`PatientID` INT NOT NULL ,
PRIMARY KEY ( `ID` )
);
INSERT INTO `patients` (`Name`) VALUES ('Ara'), ('Sada'), ('Pada'), ('Lada');
INSERT INTO `controls` (`Text`, `Type`) VALUES ('age', 'textbox'), ('alergy', 'checkbox');
INSERT INTO `controlvalues` (`ControlID`, `Value`, `PatientID`) VALUES 
  (1, '23', 1), 
  (2, 'true', 1),
  (1, '25', 2),
  (2, 'false', 2),
  (1, '23', 3),
  (2, 'false', 3),
  (1, '23', 4), 
  (2, 'true', 4);
```

And the query:

```
SELECT PatientID, COUNT(PatientID) AS PatCount, p.Name
FROM controlvalues cv
LEFT JOIN patients p ON p.ID = cv.PatientID
WHERE ((ControlID = 1 AND Value = '23')
   OR (ControlID = 2 AND Value = 'true'))
GROUP BY PatientID
HAVING PatCount = 2
;
```

Comment: I have tried this query before but it returns every patient that their age is 23 or they have allergy but I need the patients that have both allergy and they are 23 years old

Comment: Sure? I have edited my code above (added two more patients) and it gives back only PatID 1 and 4, as it should. But you can not test it on SQL Fiddle ( http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/318e2/18 ) because of an error there... Test it locally on your dev enviroment.

Comment: @Billy - Not sure why join and group by is introduced.  This should be fine I guess. Please correct me if I'm wrong.  select * from controlvalues WHERE ((ControlID = 1 AND Value = '23') OR (ControlID = 2 AND Value = 'true'))

Answer (score 1):

### Exists

You can get your answer without needing to pivot your data. The most direct approach (from my perspective) is using `EXISTS`, which reflects very directly your statement:

```
SELECT
     p.ID, p.Name
FROM
     patients p
WHERE
    EXISTS 
    (
        SELECT 1
        FROM controlvalues cv1
        WHERE p.ID = cv1.PatientID
              AND cv1.controlId = 1
              AND cv1.value = '23'
    )
    AND
    EXISTS
    (
        SELECT 1
        FROM controlvalues cv2
        WHERE p.ID = cv2.PatientID
              AND cv2.controlId = 2
              AND cv2.value = 'true'
    ) ;
```

Which will just return:

```
ID | Name
-: | :---
 1 | Ara
```

---

### Join

As an alternative, you can change the `EXISTS` to `JOIN`s:

```
SELECT
     p.ID, p.Name
FROM
     patients p
     JOIN controlvalues cv1 
         ON cv1.PatientID = p.ID AND cv1.controlId = 1 AND cv1.value = '23'
     JOIN controlvalues cv2 
         ON cv2.PatientID = p.ID AND cv2.controlId = 2 AND cv2.value = 'true' ;
```

which will return the same results. The query is more concise, but, in my opinion a little bit more difficult to read.

The execution plans (as of MariaDB 10.2) are the same, provided the right indexes (or, in my case, the primary key) have been defined.

---

### Pivot

If you really want to pivot your data, that's how you would do it:

```
SELECT
    p.ID, p.Name,
    max(case when controlId = 1 then value end) AS controlId1 /* age */,
    max(case when controlId = 2 then value end) AS controlId2 /* allergy */
FROM
    patients p
    JOIN controlvalues cv ON cv.PatientId = p.ID 
GROUP BY
    p.ID ;
```

This is the pivoted table:

```
ID | Name | controlId1 | controlId2
-: | :--- | :--------- | :---------
 1 | Ara  | 23         | true      
 2 | Sada | 25         | false
```

... and that's how you would use it:

```
SELECT
    pp.ID, pp.Name
FROM
    (
    SELECT
        p.ID, p.Name,
        max(case when controlId = 1 then value end) AS controlId1,
        max(case when controlId = 2 then value end) AS controlId2
    FROM
        patients p
        JOIN controlvalues cv ON cv.PatientId = p.ID 
    GROUP BY
        p.ID 
    ) AS pp
WHERE
    pp.controlId1 = '23' AND pp.controlId2 = 'true';
```

```
ID | Name
-: | :---
 1 | Ara
```

The execution plan for the *pivoted* table, however, might probably be worse (specially in a big table).

You can check everything in *dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.2&fiddle=71cf2d5acd0bf90da2935696b29dc9be)*